# Why can I only boot once from a UEFI boot entry?

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, acer-aspire

On an Acer Aspire XC-105 I can only boot into a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 only once for each entry that is made in the UEFI, with the UEFI entry no longer existing after a restart.

For some reason, the UEFI entry gets removed after the system is shut down or restarted after having boot from that specific entry.

This also applies to custom boot entries added manually.

```
# modprobe efivars
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0004
BootOrder: 0004,0005,0002,0001
Boot0001  Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002  Ubuntu Shim 2
Boot0004* Ubuntu Shim 4
Boot0005  Ubuntu Shim 5
```

The `Ubuntu Shim #` entries are entries manually added with this command:

```
efibootmgr -c -w -l '\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi' -L "Ubuntu Shim #"
```

Once I restart the system it gives the following error:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot Device
or Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key
```

If I press ctrl+alt+delete, and press DEL to enter the Bios Setup, I can see `Ubuntu Shim 5` as the first boot option, and I can now boot Ubuntu successfully, and the previous Boot entry is no longer there.

```
# modprobe efivars
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0005
BootOrder: 0005,0002,0001
Boot0001  Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002  Ubuntu Shim 2
Boot0005* Ubuntu Shim 5
```

If I restart the system again and immediately enter the BIOS, I see `Windows Boot Manager` as the first boot option, but I can now boot Ubuntu successfully, and the previous Boot entry is no longer there.

```
# modprobe efivars
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0002
BootOrder: 0002,0001
Boot0001  Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* Ubuntu Shim 2
```

I now have to create new UEFI boot entries if I want to be able to boot Ubuntu again.

Why do the UEFI entries disappear on the next boot once they have been booted from?

Comment: Looks to be the same issue, but no solution: https://superuser.com/questions/801963/how-to-add-efi-entry-by-efibootmgr

Comment: And another one that looks like it has some explanation and (maybe?) a solution: [Why does Linux's UEFI entry disappear at each boot?](https://superuser.com/questions/1123023/why-does-linuxs-uefi-entry-disappear-at-each-boot?rq=1) and [this one has some explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/1117803/uefi-boot-not-showing-ubuntu-grub).